# How to set the value of partialErrorsByItemID on CKError for testing?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, cloudkit, xctest

I want to test my error handling for a class handling CloudKit Operations. I'd like to be able to construct a `CKError` with a particular partial error, so that I can pass it into the Operation's completion block under test.

I can init a `CKError` with the `.partialError` code but as the `partialErrorsByItemID` Dictionary is get-only, I can't set the partial errors.

```
let error = CKError(.partialError)
error.partialErrorsByItemID = ["TestItemID": CKError(.zoneNotFound)] // => Cannot assign to property: 'partialErrorsByItemID' is a get-only property
```

Is there a way to control the value of `partialErrorsByItemID`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can assign the value of `partialErrorsByItemID` by providing the relevant key/value pair in the `userInfo` Dictionary, and using the `init(_:userInfo:)` initializer:

```
let error = CKError(.partialFailure, userInfo: [
    CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey: ["TestItemID": CKError(.zoneNotFound)]
])
```